# Удаление элементов из массива в AngularJs

Tags: javascript, массивы, angularjs

Помогите решить проблему... при выборе всех элементов и если нажимаю на удалить сразу удаляются не все выбранные элементы а скажем выбрал пять сначала удаляются 3 потом еще раз нажимаю на удалить удаляются 2 потом нажимаю еще и удаляется последний.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 var notes = [
 {selected: false, title: "How to study AngularJS"},{selected: false, title: "How to study AngularJS"},{selected: false, title: "How to study AngularJS"},{selected: false, title: "How to study AngularJS"},{selected: false, title: "How to study AngularJS"},
 ];

 $scope.notes = notes;
 var edit = false;
 $scope.toggleEdit = function(){
  if (edit === false) {
   $scope.showEdit = function(){
    return edit = true;
   }
  }else{
   $scope.showEdit = function(){
    return edit = false;
   }
  }
 };
 $scope.addNew = function(title){
  notes.push({
   title : notes.title
  });
 };
 $scope.selectAll = function(){
  for(var j = 0;j < notes.length;j++){
   var selAll = notes[j];
   if (selAll.selected === false) {
    selAll.selected = true;
   }else{
    selAll.selected = false;
   }
  }
 }
 $scope.remove = function(){
  for(var i = 0;i < notes.length;i++){
   if (notes[i].selected === true) {
    notes.splice(notes.indexOf(notes[i]), 1);
   };
  };
 };
}]);
```

```css
ul{
 list-style-type: none;
}
body{
 font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}
.btn-primary{
 display: block;
 margin-left: 38px;
}
i.fa-plus-square-o{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
i.fa-plus-square-o::before{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
h1{
 margin: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.add_new{
 display: block;
}
.item{
 padding: 10px 30px;
 margin: 5px 0;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 14px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 text-align: left;
}
.title{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.description{
 font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
  <h1>Your Notes</h1>
  <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="toggleEdit()"></i>
  <pre> {{notes.length}} </pre>
  <pre>  </pre>
  <div class="add_new" ng-show="showEdit()">
   <input type="text" ng-model="notes.title">
   <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addNew(title)">Add New Note</button>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="selectAll()">Select All</button>
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="note in notes">
    <div class="item">
     <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control control--checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="note.selected">
       <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
     </div>
     <div class="title">
      <h1 class="description"> {{note.title}} </h1>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="delete">
   <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove()">Delete selected</button>
  </div>
 </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы неправильно удаляете элементы из массива (после удаление первого элемента сбиваются индексы). Используйте встроенный `.filter` (может не работать в старых браузерах) или библиотеки вроде lodash.

```
$scope.remove = function() {
    $scope.notes = $scope.notes.filter(function(node) {
        return !note.selected;
    });
};
```

Вариант с циклом

```
$scope.remove = function(){
        for(var i = 0;i < notes.length;i++){
            if (notes[i].selected === true) {
                notes.splice(notes.indexOf(notes[i]), 1);
                i--; // Коррекция индекса после удаления
            };
        };
    };
```

Comment: получился  Огромное спасибо вам!!!!!